# What justcodeanalysis.net4.exe * 32 done in my system to make my system slow?

Tags: visual-studio, telerik, visual-studio-addins, justcode

Today I tried [Telerik JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) and I found that my system performed extremely slow. I found in task manager that they run a `.exe` on my system called `justcodeanalysis.net4.exe * 32` that makes my system very slow. Before it worked fine; JustCode Visual Studio performance was good.

What should I do? Do I need to uninstall it or take any action to have it perform better on my system?

Answer (score 1):

JustCode performs a full analysis of the code in your solution in order to provide quick refactoring, code navigation, and error reporting while you work on your project. The analysis occurs at start up, so you should only see a performance hit when you first open your project. For small projects the performance hit should be negligible, but for very large projects you may have to wait a few seconds. Analysis does continue while you work, but only new or modified code is analyzed.

You can tell JustCode what you want it to analyze and the interval at which it should refresh. Just go to **JustCode | Options | Code Analysis** from the main menu in Visual Studio. Update the **Code analysis refresh interval** to have it analyze your code more or less frequently, and select/deselect the languages you want JustCode to analyze. You can also provide filters for files, or even entire projects, you want JustCode to exclude from its analysis.

In my experience, JustCode is very fast and an invaluable code refactoring tool. The slight startup performance impact is a small price to pay for the features you get in exchange.

Check out this [blog post](http://www.telerikwatch.com/2011/05/add-in-start-up-time-in-visual-studio.html) by [Todd Anglin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54305/), Telerik's Chief Evangelist, which shows real metrics regarding the impact JustCode and other Visual Studio plugins have on start up time.

I hope this helps!